# Change class but click not recognizing the new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have the following html:

```
<div class="showMap" id="mapVis" style="cursor:pointer">(Show map)</div>
<div id="map">hello world</div>
```

Div `#map` is hidden as shown below (there's a reason for hiding it this way, it holds a google map), then I want to click `(Show map)` and the div appears. This is ok. Then I change the class and the html of the `#mapVis` div and want the next click to hide `#map` - but it doesn't. Honestly I don't know what its doing but its as if it ignores the new class and reverts to the actions as if previous class was still attached to the `#mapVis` div.

Here's the JQuery:

```
var map2 = $('#map');
map2.css('position','absolute').css('left','-9999em');

$('.showMap').click(function(){
    map2.hide().css('position','relative').css('left','0em').slideDown();
    $('#mapVis').removeClass('showMap').addClass('hideMap').html('(Hide map)');
});

$('.hideMap').click(function(){
    map2.css('position','absolute').css('left','-9999em');
    $('#mapVis').removeClass('hideMap').addClass('showMap').html('(Show map)');
});
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/jhXV4/)

Comment: You didn't define jQuery in your fiddle.

Comment: Your problem is that you bind click event to dom element , and after that you change it's class , the event is already binded,you need to rebind the event or check value of class before doing anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your selectors have to be evaluated dynamically you need to use event delegation.

When you use normal event registration the selectors are evaluated only at the time of event registration and any changes done on the element will not reflect in the registered handlers.

```
var map2 = $('#map');
map2.css('position', 'absolute').css('left', '-9999em');
$(document).on('click', '.showMap', function () {
    console.log('hey2');
    $('#map').hide().css('position', 'relative').css('left', '0em').slideDown();
    $('#mapVis').removeClass('showMap').addClass('hideMap').html('(Hide map)');
});
$(document).on('click', '.hideMap', function () {
    console.log('hey');
    $('#map').hide();
    $('#map').css('position', 'absolute').css('left', '-9999em');
    $('#mapVis').removeClass('hideMap').addClass('showMap').html('(Show map)');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9998K/)

Answer (score 2):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7At32/

this is a sample, BUT you can modify to your requirement

```
$('#mapVis').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("showMap")) {
        $('#map').show();
        $(this).removeClass('showMap').addClass('hideMap').html('(Hide map)');
    } else {
        $('#map').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('hideMap').addClass('showMap').html('(Show map)');
    }
});
```